# How to make Foreground color of all controls White by default

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

1- Create a new WPF application.

2- Add some controls to your WPF application.

3- See that Foreground color of all controls are Black by default.

How to make Foreground color of all controls White by default?

[image]

Comment: For some controls, it's enough to set the foreground colour of their parent `Window`, although I'm not sure it works for _every_ control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Foreground color of all controls are Black by default." because it is Windows theme setting.

you can assign your own foreground brush using `ControlTextBrushKey` key

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey }" Color="Green"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

this setting will be immediately seen in designer in property grid

Comment: I just get `SolidColorBrush is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.`

Answer (score 3):

You could try to define an implicit `TextBox` style in your window's XAML or in `App.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
...
```

That's probably the closest you get to setting the text colour of all controls in one place.